# Filter wp_query to search post title in function

Tags: wp-query

I'm making a query to pull posts from my post query based on a user entry in a form.  I want to keep the form simple so I'm hoping to only have to use one field.  That field would say search part number or product title.  It's an going to be an Ajax response. Here's the code I have right now:

```
function led_search_function(){

    $args = array(
              'post_type'   => 'al_product',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
    );
 
    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) && $_POST['categoryfilter'] )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );
 
    // create $args['meta_query'] array if one of the following fields is filled
    if( isset( $_POST['part_number'] ) && $_POST['part_number'] )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'OR' ); // OR means that both below conditions of meta_query should be true

    
    if( isset( $_POST['part_number'] ) && $_POST['part_number'] ) {
        //checks for the part number
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'part_number',
            'value' => $_POST['part_number'],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
        //checks if variations have part numbers to add to the array
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'product_variations_$_part_number',
            'value' => $_POST['part_number'],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
       }
 
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
              echo '<h2>Your Search Results</h2><div class="productCategories grid">';
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
                                    <div class="product_cat">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('small');?>
                                <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                    <?php 
                                    $subtitle = get_field('subtitle');
                                    if ( $subtitle ) { 
                                        echo '<h3 class="entry-subtitle">'.$subtitle.'</h3>';
                                    }
                    ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
    
                        <?php
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No lights found';
    endif;
 
    die();
}
```

It's a bit misleading right now because the field on the form is still called "part_number" even though it will search for everything.

I'm hoping to be able to add a 3rd part to the query that will search for the post title as well (or parts of it...so if the someone typed "sun" it would return products called "sunbeast" or "sun set light".

The 2nd catch is that if that the search term is NOT in the title but is still a part number I need it to return a the results still.

I see that i can use the "s" variable but that searches content too and is strict on title case.  Is there a better method?

**UPDATE**
Based On @sally-cj I've tried with this:  (all in my functions.php) but it returns all products no matter what I input.

```
<?php
//enqueue product filter ajax js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'product_finder_scripts' );
function product_finder_scripts() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-filter-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
    } 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'led_search_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'led_search_function');
 
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'product_variations_$", "meta_key LIKE 'product_variations_%", $where);
    return $where;
}
//add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');

function led_search_function(){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'al_product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
    );
 
    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) && $_POST['categoryfilter'] )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );
 
    /**
    // create $args['meta_query'] array if one of the following fields is filled
    if( isset( $_POST['part_number'] ) && $_POST['part_number'] )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'OR' ); // OR means that both below conditions of meta_query should be true

    
    if( isset( $_POST['part_number'] ) && $_POST['part_number'] ) {
        //checks for the part number
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'part_number',
            'value' => $_POST['part_number'],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
        //checks if variations have part numbers to add to the array
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'product_variations_$_part_number',
            'value' => $_POST['part_number'],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
    } 
    **/

    add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'my_posts_clauses', 10, 2 );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'my_posts_clauses', 10 );
    
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        echo '<h2>Your Search Results</h2><div class="productCategories grid">';
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="product_cat">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('small');?>
                    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                    <?php 
                        $subtitle = get_field('subtitle');
                        if ( $subtitle ) { 
                            echo '<h3 class="entry-subtitle">'.$subtitle.'</h3>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No lights found';
    endif;

    
    die();
}

// In the theme's functions.php file, or somewhere in your plugin:
function my_posts_clauses( $clauses, $query ) {
    $part_number = $_POST['part_number'] ?? '';

    if ( strlen( $part_number ) && ! is_admin() ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $part_number2 = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $part_number ) . '%';

        $clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta my_mt1 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = my_mt1.post_id";

        // Search in the metadata part_number.
        $where = $wpdb->prepare( "(my_mt1.meta_key = 'part_number'
            AND my_mt1.meta_value LIKE %s)", $part_number2 );

        // Search in the metadata product_variations_$_part_number.
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR (my_mt1.meta_key = 'product_variations_\$_part_number'
            AND my_mt1.meta_value LIKE %s)", $part_number2 );

        // Search in post title.
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR ({$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE %s)", $part_number2 );

        $clauses['where'] .= " AND ( $where )";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes 2 queries is easiest. Perhaps do a custom search on title and then use `post__in` for the second query.

Comment: yeah, that's my first inclination too, but wanted to see if there was a "slicker" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it via a single `WP_Query` call, then you can use the [`posts_clauses` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/).

And the trick is, don't set the `part_number` and `product_variations_$_part_number` meta queries via the `meta_query` arg, but use the above hook instead, i.e. manually build the SQL clauses.

### Working Example

Note: In your `led_search_function()` code, the above-mentioned meta queries should first be removed.

```php
// In the theme's functions.php file, or somewhere in your plugin:
function my_posts_clauses( $clauses, $query ) {
    $part_number = $_POST['part_number'] ?? '';

    if ( strlen( $part_number ) && ! is_admin() ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $part_number2 = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $part_number ) . '%';

        $clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta my_mt1 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = my_mt1.post_id";

        // Search in the metadata part_number.
        $where = $wpdb->prepare( "(my_mt1.meta_key = 'part_number'
            AND my_mt1.meta_value LIKE %s)", $part_number2 );

        // Search in the metadata product_variations_$_part_number.
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR (my_mt1.meta_key = 'product_variations_\$_part_number'
            AND my_mt1.meta_value LIKE %s)", $part_number2 );

        // Search in post title.
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR ({$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE %s)", $part_number2 );

        $clauses['where'] .= " AND ( $where )";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

So add that function and then make the WP query like so (you could instead use a closure than adding/removing the filter like below, but that will be up to you on implementing it):

```php
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'my_posts_clauses', 10, 2 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'my_posts_clauses', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  I don't think I quite understand though.  Can you check if I did it correctly in my update?

Comment: Yes, you did it correctly. But I didn't notice you're doing the filter via the admin AJAX, which means `is_admin()` is true. So try removing the `&& ! is_admin()` in the `my_posts_clauses()` function?

Comment: I wish I had seen your answer earlier.  I don't want you to think this isn't important.  It's returning a search but not fully.  It seems the first clause (`// Search in the metadata part_number.`) but not the 2nd (`// Search in the metadata product_variations_$_part_number.`)  I tried adding another field that was in my product variations and it didn't provide results in the search either.  Its so close...any other good ideas for me?

Comment: Sorry for the delay and sorry if this sounded silly.. but are you sure the *meta key* is actually indeed `product_variations_$_part_number` (note the `$` symbol)? Try `var_dump( $query->request );` and see if the SQL is good? (You can paste it in your comment or add it to the question)